# what does $\mathcal{L^1}$ in $\mathcal{L^1}(S,\sum,\mu)$mean?

Tags: measure-theory

What does actually $\mathcal{L^1}$ in $\mathcal{L^1}(S,\sum,\mu)$ mean? Is it a set of functions that are measurable? Or what?

Comment: It means [$L^1$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces).

Comment: In general it means the set of functions whose integral on some space with respect to some measure is finite.

Comment: Shall I delete this question?